# I am having trouble with running a jar file

Tags: java, bash, classpath

I try to run a java program with the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

java -cp dl.jar Elevator
```

Elevator is the main class. But I get an error every time.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Elevator
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Elevator
```

My classes are all in the .jar file under the directory src/hw4. I have tried adding src/hw4 to the classpath, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use direct class name. You have to use the full package.

If in your IDE you wrote for exammple: `package hw4;` and you want to run the class `Elevator`, use this :

```
java -cp dl.jar hw4.Elevator
```

It seems to correspond to your jar file.

The `src` folder is not on the class path. It's just a directory in your IDE to order all files as project files and project content.

Comment: I just put it all into the default package to make things easier. Still, I can only get the bash script running if I put my makefile and bash script in the src directory and run them from there. If I do it any other way, I'll get a ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: And if you run manually from command line ?

Comment: STill get the same error. "Error: Could not find or load main class Elevator
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Elevator".  I have my bash script just outside of my src folder. I try:  java -cp ./src/dl.jar Elevator  .  I'm not sure how I'm supposed to run a jar folder located in a sub-directory.

Comment: Can you check the package ordering in the `dl.jar` ? Do it just by opening the file such as an archive zip

Comment: the directories are META-INF and src. MANIFEST.MF is in the META-INF directory and all my class files are in src

Comment: MANIFEST.MF doesn't contain much. Just the version number: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 11.0.11 (Ubuntu)